# Java Web Service Client issue - HTTP Header - Host Field

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

We have a web service hidden behind an F5 appliance.  The F5 accepts https requests, decrypts the message, then sends the decrypted message to our web service.  The web service responds with a decrypted message to the F5, then the F5 encrypts and sends back to the originator of the web service request.

This web service works for clients written in some languages, but not others.  This question refers to the Java implementation based on the Websphere JRE and libraries.  Whereas the other (working) languages set the Host field of the HTTP header to ourhost.net, Java (when sending over https) is setting the Host field of the HTTP header to ourhost.net:443 .  I realize that https comes in over port 443, but I don't understand why Java feels it is necessary to include that port in the Host field.

Any ideas?

Comment: So this is using the built-in Web Services client proxy/wrapper libraries in WebSphere, correct? Which version of WebSphere, and which API type? JAX-WS? JAX-RPC? Presumably the WSDL doesn't have :443 in the service endpoint, correct? Can you look at the generated code and see if the :443 is in that?

Comment: Yes - built in ... WebSphere 7 ... JAX-WS.  The WSDL does not have a 443 in it, and the generated code does not have a 443 in it.

Our current solution is to have the F5 update the HTTP header (removing the 443) using an I-Rule (not sure what that is).

Answer (score 0):

Since 443 is the default port for HTTPS, it is not required to include it in the Host header, but it is also not incorrect to do so. See [section 14.23 of the HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23).